# Private registry push fail: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: docker, nexus

I was using docker in linux machine where I was pulling images from my local docker repo over http authentication. Now I need to use the same thing on windows setup. Issue is when I am trying to pull image using command

```
docker pull <IP>:port/abc/xyz
```

it gives me error Private registry push fail: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

I have modified the daemon.json file to

```
{"registry-mirrors":[],"insecure-registries":["<IP>:port"], "debug":true, "experimental": false}
```

even after this its not getting started. And showing me the same error.

Comment: Did you restart the Docker daemon?

Comment: yes i have restarted it. I have used ankit's answer and it worked. just curious to know why it was not working with other parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. What you have to do is just give the insecure-registries, and remove all other configurations. Just copy paste the below json inside daemon.json file ( available in "C:\Users{user-name}.docker\daemon.json" or "/etc/docker/daemon.json")

```
{
   "insecure-registries" :["<IP>:port"]
}
```

Comment: thanks ankit i was stucked, but didn't get why it was not working with other values

Comment: what if we must use other configurations then?